# How to find top 5 duplicate entries in a MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the highest number of duplicate rows in a SQL table.  I'm able to get the count, but the number will dynamically change from time to time.  So would I need to add the count to the table and then find the max of the count column?  Or would I just need to find the max of the counted column without adding it to the table?  I hope those questions make sense.  Here's what I have so far.

```
$countQuery = "SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num FROM $tblEmerg GROUP BY breakers";
$count = mysqli_query($db, $countQuery) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){
        echo "<p>" .$row['breakers'] ." - " .$row['num'] ."</p>";
    }
```

This gives me the output of:

```
APU [1] - 3    
APU [5] - 1    
APU [7] - 1    
AVIONICS[1] - 2    
FC[5] - 1    
FC[6] - 1    
FC[7] - 1    
FC[9] - 1
```

Which is what I want, but as I mentioned, the 'num' will change dynamically and I want to just return the top 5 results.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: add an order by and a limit. such as `ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5 `

Comment: @Doon just realized you'd already answered in a comment :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num 
  FROM $tblEmerg 
  GROUP BY breakers having num > 1 order by count(breakers) desc limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `ORDER BY COUNT(breakers) DESC LIMIT 5` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the required result.

```
SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num FROM $tblEmerg GROUP BY breakers ORDER BY COUNT(breakers) DESC LIMIT 5
```